# Is there a way to import data from an excel file into an already existing kivy app

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd, import-from-excel

So I was making a `Kivy` program in which it imports data from an Excel file of which I give the path as an input.

I am currently using the `read_excel` function of pandas to read the file.
it works completely fine when im running it as a program.

My query is would it still run if I converted the `Kivy` file into an android application.

if not, is there any other way I could do so, using any other module in python?

```
path = input(“enter path: “)
file = pd.read_excel(path, engine=‘openpyxl’, sheet_name=‘Sheet1’)
```

Unfortunately, I wasn’t able to upload the complete code.

Comment: what have you tried ? the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You would add a TextInput to your kivy program and enter the file path in the text input and have a button (or hitting enter) would then load the file.